# Is there a way to analyze what's using frametime or view all simulated meshes at once?

Tags: physics, frame-rate

I have relatively large scene in which I did some cloth simulations. I'm sure I don't have any simulation enabled (went through all visible and invisible meshes). But even without apparently nothing running, I get only 2fps. Surely there must be some simulation still running that I can't find. Is there a way to check that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, turns out using simplify solved the issue. I didn't know that the subD modifieres are such a frame eater for nonanimated objects.